# Android deep linking not wotking with assetlinks.json

Tags: android, react-native, url, next.js

I am trying to implement deep linking to my android app.

This is my AndroidManifest with the intent-filters:

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
      android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="mygainplan" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:host="www.my-gainplan.com" />
        <data android:pathPrefix="/workouts" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I am using react-navigation for handling deep links inside my app with this config

```js
const linking = {
  prefixes: [
    'https://www.my-gainplan.com',
    'mygainplan://',
    'https://my-gainplan.com',
  ],
  config: {
    screens: {
      MyWorkouts: 'workouts',
    },
  },
};
```

To make this work with my website, I have added the following assetlinks.json to my website

```json
[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.mygainplan",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "FA:C6:17:45:DC:09:03:78:6F:B9:ED:E6:2A:96:2B:39:9F:73:48:F0:BB:6F:89:9B:83:32:66:75:91:03:3B:9C"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

The sha256 is the one from the android debug keystore.

When I run the app in debug mode, links with the prefix mygainplan:// work just fine, but links from the website (https://www.my-gainplan.com/workouts) just open the web browser and not the app. Why is this happening?

Comment: How are you testing? If you are using the browser address bar, that will not work. Try a link in a Web page or similar content. Also note that deeplinks are not supported by default in all browsers.

Comment: I am using the pm package uri-scheme for this. I use it via npx (npx uri-scheme open https://www.my-gainplan.com/workouts --android) which should work fine

Comment: It opens the chrome browser on my phone, I believe crome should support this feature

Comment: @JaRoMaster can you share your complete AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Hi JaRoMaster, when you create a deep link you have the ability to test it. does this test passed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add android:autoVerify="true" to the intent filter that specifies the domain aswell. With that added, the deep link works just fine

Answer (score 0):

You Don't think that you're coming to it from the correct way.
The app is associated with the bundle identifier same as the deep link.

[image]

1. Is the domain you want to add
2. The bundle identifier associated with you app.
3. `Select Keystore file` and add your desired keystore from the app tree.
4. Click on `Generate Digital Asset Links file`

When clicked on the `Generate Digital Asset Links file` you should see the next section:

[image]

Notice that you'll have to save the file and load it to the link shown in section [link](https://testdomain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json)

After added your the downloaded file to the link mentioned you can click on `Link and Verify`

When you finish all and the test pass than you'll be able to run the app using the deep link.

**Please notice that it's important that the bundle identifier is the same on both.**

Comment: You don't need any software to generate the assetlinks.json file. My file was correct, I was facing the problem due to a mistake in my AndroidManifest as described above

Comment: Well, that's android studio. not just a software. and i've used it to create deep links just as i mentioned